# Is there a maximal but not ideally prime ideal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

An ideal $P$ of a ring $R$ is called prime (In ideal sense) if for ideals  $I,J $ of $R$, $P$ contains the product ideal $IJ$ implies $P$ contains $I$ or $P$ contains $J$.

At this moment we call prime ( in ideal sense) as (ideally) prime.

I can't found a ring and one maximal ideal which is not (ideally) prime but also cannot disprove the exsitance of such an animal.

What I've got is If such an animal exists, it must lies in a non commutative ring, or a  non unital ring (actually stronger, $R^2$ is strictly contained in $R$)

Thank you.

By the way, I have an example that an ideal is maximal but not prime in the usual sense ( for any two elements $a,b $ in $R$, $ab$ in $P$ implies $ a$ in $P $ or $b $ in $P$ ), unfortunately that non prime ideal is Ideally prime. It is the zero ideal in the  matrix ring with entry in an division ring.

Comment: I'm not familliar with the ideally prime definition however a maximal ideal is always prime in regards to your last paragraph

Comment: @SheelStueber no, zero is maximal but not prime in that ring

Comment: @SheelStueber Not quite - there's something subtle going on here. When the ring R is commutative, what you said is true, but in this case the two definitions are equivalent. (When the ring R is non-commutative, well, most people will still tell you that all maximal ideals are prime - but they are *not* working with the same definition of "prime" as the one given in this post!)

Comment: @Billy even commutative is not enough, also need unital or R^2=R

Comment: ah i supposed all rings were unital+ commutative my fault

Comment: I'm curious to know where you encountered this as called "ideally prime." I can't seem to find any google hits mainly because of other instances of the words next to each other. In noncommutative algebra books, this is simply the definition of "prime ideal," and the commutative version is called "completely prime" or "absolutely prime", when needed.

Comment: @rschwieb yes this def is only used in our notes, and not standard. I use this to emphasize the difference with prime  in common sense

Comment: @Michael.L Well, the *definition* is standard in noncommutative algebra... it's just the *name* that's nonstandard to me :) Although it is perfectly sensible given your context, apparently!

Answer (score 1):

When $R$ is unital, the answer is no.

Let $P$ be a maximal ideal, and choose any two ideals $I$ and $J$ such that $I\not\subseteq P$ and $J\not\subseteq P$. Then $P+I$ and $P+J$ are ideals of $R$ that contain $P$ *and* some stuff not in $P$ - and so they're *bigger* than $P$, so (as $P$ was maximal) they must be equal to $R$.

In particular, we can write $1\in R = P+I$ as $1 = p+i$ for some $p\in P$ and $i\in I$, and $1\in R = P+J$ as $1 = p'+j$ for some $p'\in P$ and $j\in J$. Multiplying these two expressions together, we get
$$1 = (p+i)(p'+j) = pp' + ip' + pj + ij.$$
But it's obvious that $pp'$, $ip'$ and $pj$ are in $P$. Hence $ij\in P$ if and only if $1\in P$. But we know already that $1\not\in P$, because $P$ is a maximal ideal (and hence by definition $P\neq R$). So $ij\not\in P$, and hence $IJ\not\subseteq P$.

When $R$ is non-unital, the answer is yes. For example, the non-unital ring $R = 2\mathbb{Z}$ contains the maximal ideal $P = 4\mathbb{Z}$, and the ideals $I = J = 2\mathbb{Z}$. Then $IJ\subseteq P$, but $I, J\not\subseteq P$.

Comment: Notice that R need not to be unital

Comment: Ah. Updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: (In fact, didn't you stumble on this answer yourself? I didn't understand what you meant by $R^2 \subset R$ until I came up with this example, but I'm presuming this is what you meant.)

Comment: Wow, I have to say it's brilliant construction. I should have come up with this. Thank you a lot, I appreciate it.

Comment: haha actually I before I want to find this I haven't raise any example such that R^2 is strictly contained in R .. So I said I should have...